# subtype reference argument compile error on gcc

Tags: c++

I have a problem compiling a c++ program with gcc version 4.6.3; I can compile this program with microsoft compiler (v 9.0) without problems.
This program is using some of my libraries I always used with microsoft compiler.

problem is when I try to pass a reference as argument that is a subtype of another: pseudo example here:

```
class ObjManager{..}

class SubObjMng : public ObjManager{
public:
    inline SubObjMng() : ObjManager(0, ... ){}
};

class Test{
public:
   Test(int i, ObjManager &obj_mng);
}


int main(){

SubObjMng myobjmng;

Test t(0, myobjmng);    //GCC ERROR HERE

}
```

output of the error is (real output for my program):

```
globals.h:227:40: error: no matching function for call to cdk::HashMap::HashMap(unsigned int, cdk::PtrObjMng, cdk::cstrObjMng)
globals.h:227:40: note: candidates are:
contrib/cdklib/cdk_struct.h:485:12: note: cdk::HashMap::HashMap(uint32_t, cdk::ObjManager&, cdk::ObjManager&)
contrib/cdklib/cdk_struct.h:485:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from cdk::PtrObjMng to cdk::ObjManager&
```

anyone can help?
thanks!

Comment: Hi Giuseppe, I don't know if you've provided enough code here. It looks like somewhere in ObjManager or SubObjMng, you're defining something that uses a HashMap. But probably nobody can help without being able to see that code :)

Comment: It would be most useful if you created an actualy piece of code we can feed into a compiler, and attach the output of what you received when you fed it to your compiler.

Comment: ok ! I ll try to be more exaustive! ;)

Comment: If your naming convention is to be believed, it looks like `HashMap()` wants a pointer to an `ObjManager`, not a reference...

Answer (score 0):

`cdk::PtrObjMng` should inherit from `cdk::ObjMng`, making polymorphism possible through references. Otherwise this is a no-go according to what the compiler says.

Of course this might not be the root of your problem, I wish we could see the implementation of your constructor.